# Access mongoose non-schema values in Jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I have a really weird problem in Jade where I cannot access the values that aren't defined in the Schema.

I'm using `strict:false` on my schema and saving values to it. My data looks like this:

```
{
 "title" : "This is a title in the schema",
 "notInSchema" : "This will never show up"
}
```

This works:

```
h1= post.title
```

This doesn't work:

```
h1= post.notInSchema
```

If I dump all my data into the template, I can see both pieces of data:

```
pre= JSON.stringify(options,null,'\t')      //{"title" : "This is a title in the schema", "notInSchema" : "This will never show up"}
```

If I add `notInSchema` to my schema, it shows up. How can I do this without adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the raw Mongoose document to Jade, pass its serialized version instead:

```
res.render('yourtemplate', {
  post : post.toJSON() // .toJSON() is also called by JSON.stringify()
});
```

I believe Mongoose only creates accessors on a document for fields that are in the schema. Any other fields, even though they are stored in the database, don't get one so can't be accessed directly.

The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) seems to suggest something similar:

> NOTE: Any key/val set on the instance that does not exist in your
>   schema is always ignored, regardless of schema option.

**EDIT:** since you're dealing with result sets, you need to call `toJSON` on each document in it. The easiest way to do so is using `map` (hope I get the CF syntax right):

```
res.render "admin",
  title   : "Admin Dashboard"
  results : results
  users   : results.users.map (user) ->
    user.toJSON()
  messages: req.flash() || {}
```

Although that would still leave `results` 'unprocessed'. Alternatively, you could leave the mapping to the separate steps in your `async.series`. For instance:

```
 Company
   .find()
   .exec (err,companies)->
     next(null,companies.map (company) ->
       company.toJSON()
     )
```

Or use `toJSON` in your template on any object that you need to access those "unschema'd" properties for.

Comment: How do you pass the Mongoose result(s) to your templates?

Comment: Here is the entire function, I'd like it on everything, but `options` is the most important right now

https://gist.github.com/wesbos/bd274e9f7112e4476522

Comment: @Wes Edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: @Wes a shortcut for the `map/toJSON` operation would be this: `users : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.users))` (which looks a bit silly, but works pretty much the same)

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
model.find({Branch:branch},function (err, docs){
if (err) res.send(err)

 res.render('index', 
    {tree: tree,
      articulos: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs)) 
    })})
   });
```